# Changing space between two radio buttons from the same group

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, radio-button

is it possible to change the space between two horizontal radio buttons? Both buttons are in the same group and I would like to move the right one ("Clear Selection") more to the right so it matches with the ones from another group below.

```
                <v-radio-group v-model="consent.newselection2"
                row
                   >
                  <v-radio
                   class="radio"
                    color="yellow"
                    v-for="item in conclusionnewitems2"
                    :rules="rules"
                    :key="item"
                    :label="item.label"
                    :value="item.value"
                  ></v-radio>
                </v-radio-group>
```

```
conclusionnewitems2: [
       { label: "Website", value: {'var1':"On our website", 'var2': "included on our website"}},
       { label: "Clear slelection", value: "null"},
],
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a framework like Vuetify (or something similar), but as long as that doesn't overwrite your styles, you could either use a class and some CSS:

```html
<template>
  <v-radio class="radio padding-left" .../>
</template>

<style>
.padding-left {
  padding-left: 4px; // or however much you want
}
</style>
```

...or with a simple style property:

```html
<template>
  <v-radio style="padding-left: 4px;" .../>
</template>
```

---

EDIT: To only move a single one (for example no. 2):
I like to use index in the loop, and add a dynamic class like so:

```html
<template>
  <v-radio 
    v-for="(item, idx) in conclusionnewitems2"
    class="radio"
    :class="idx === 1 ? 'padding-left' : ''" 
    ...
  />
</template>
```

This means only the second one (idx == 1) will have padding-left.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is that it moves both radio buttons. I'm trying to just move the right one but because they are in the same group it proves difficult. And yes, Im using vuetify

Comment: I updated the answer :) Note that you can use `idx !== 0` or any other boolean check for  this kind of ternary operator inside the dynamic class property.